# Need help to add rule in Azure Firewall Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, firewall, windows-firewall

I am trying to add a rule in azure firewall. I have azure firewall policy where I have create network rule collection then inside the collection i have rules added. I would like add one more rule in the same network rule collection. I am using the below script to do

```
$rule = New-AzFirewallNetworkRule -Name "AllowAzureDevOps" -Description "Allow access to Azure Devops" -SourceAddress "10.0.0.0/16" -DestinationAddress AzureDevOps -DestinationPort 443 -Protocol TCP

$policy = Get-AzFirewallPolicy -Name "fw-policy" -ResourceGroupName "fw-rg"

$networkrulecollectiongroup = Get-AzFirewallPolicyRuleCollectionGroup -Name "DefaultNetworkRuleCollectionGroup" -ResourceGroupName "fw-rg" -AzureFirewallPolicyName "fw-pol"

$existingrulecollection = $networkrulecollectiongroup.Properties.RuleCollection | where {$_.Name -eq "NetworkRuleCollection"}

$existingrulecollection.Rules.Add($rule)
```

> PS C:\Users\mkumar480> $existingrulecollection.Rules.Add($rule)
>
> Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1". At
> line:1 char:1
>
> - $existingrulecollection.Rules.Add($rule)
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
>   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [AddRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.network.models.psazurefirewallnetworkrulecollection.addrule?view=az-ps-latest#microsoft-azure-commands-network-models-psazurefirewallnetworkrulecollection-addrule(microsoft-azure-commands-network-models-psazurefirewallnetworkrule)) method

`$existingrulecollection.AddRule($rule)`